# monitor cpu usage per thread on windows mobile device

Tags: c++, windows, performance, windows-ce, cpu

Is is possible to measure CPU per thread on a windows mobile (or CE 5) device programmatically (c++)?  If not, is their a utility that will monitor the CPU usage of a process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CPU usage cannot be directly measured because, unlike an x86, the ARM processor doesn't have a register for it.  You can calculate it using the [Toolhelp APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914815.aspx) to get a list of processes and their child threads and then use [GetThreadTimes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909163.aspx) to figure out how much time each thread is using.

Keep in mind that doing this calculation directly affects how much the CPU is in use.

Answer (score 4):

Someone wrote a tool that looks a lot like Task Manager on the PC:
http://www.vttoth.com/LPK/taskmanager.html

As ctacke says, it does seem to use a lot of the CPU.  It reports uses ~15%-30% of our CPU on our 800MHz ARM device.